# SciPy can't install old version Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, theano

I'm trying to install an older version of SciPy (either 0.16.1 or 0.17.0), but when I try to use pip I get the result:

`pip install scipy==0.16.1`

I get the following message

`Failed building wheel for scipy`

So I found the `.whl` file here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy but the problem is that the version here is 1.0.1, and I can't seem to find any older ones, even in the SciPy website (there are for linux and mac)

.
.

PS.
I need to use either of this versions because I'm trying to run Theano on a GPU, and the tutorial provided here http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html says this version is a requirement if there is any tutorial that is better and more up-to-date I would be appreciated

Comment: There is probably a lot of things to say (which are not targeting your question): (1) those docs say anaconda-only -> no pip-install supported! (2) theano's internal setup.py says: ```install_requires=['numpy>=1.9.1', 'scipy>=0.14', 'six>=1.9.0']```, so just use the given scipy within some anaconda-dist. (3) i would not expect newer scipy versions to fail (4) it's a bad idea to use outdated versions of numpy/scipy in general (5) theano is somewhat discontinued. It really seems those docs are outdated. Try anaconda with whatever numpy/scipy is shipped and switch to alternatives if not working.

Comment: Only version 1.0 and beyond is possible via pip on windows.

Comment: Why @percusse??